# php preg_split, get data from a web api to a mysql db

Tags: php, regex

I have an input string like this:

> {"id":1,"name":"John","age":50,"surname":"Smith","category":"something","money":500}

and I'd need to get an array like:

> Array
>
> (
>
> ```
>  [id] => 1
>
>  [name] => John
>
>  [age] => 50 
>
>  [...]
> ```
>
> )

or another way to insert that record into a mysql database...

But I'm not very familiar with regular expressions... how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is [json Format](http://www.json.org/) and you don't need to split anything you can use `json_decode` to decode it to array

```
$str = '{"id":1,"name":"John","age":50,"surname":"Smith","category":"something","money":500}';
$str = json_decode($str,true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($str);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => John
    [age] => 50
    [surname] => Smith
    [category] => something
    [money] => 500
)
```